# annonation file from xwaves to praat

Tags: phonetics, praat, intonation

There is a speech corpus (IViE: http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/files/apps/old_IViE/) which provided annoated speech files in the following format:

```
signal Cambridge_sentences/Q_no_morph/q2cma.d
type 0
comment created using xlabel Thu Jun  8 15:51:08 2000
color 100
font -*-times-medium-r-*-*-17-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
separator ;
nfields 1
#
    0.429499  100  lH-m
    0.856702  100  lM-h
```

Since it includes essential information of annotation(time point, marking), I think there should be a way for me to transform the data to a textgrid that is readable in Praat, or any suggestions on how to read it along with the sound files in Praat?

Comment: where is the annotation in your example? you just need a parser to read the file and to perform a praat file.

Answer (score 3):

Praat has already a parser that can read Xwaves file.

Open/Read > Read from special tier file > Read IntervalTier from Xwaves

Then these labels can be transferred into TextGrid file.

New > Create Textgrid